# Time comparison in html using NGIF Condition - Angular

Tags: time, angular-ng-if

I am in requirement for solution where I have one Admin posts application for an Android app. I have placed a delete button for post. The requirement is that delete button must be shown for 5 minutes from time of posting.

Here is the ngif condition  which I have used..

```
*ngIf="((((post.CreatedDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy') == (PresentDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy')) && ((post.CreatedDate | date:'HH') == (post.CreatedDate | date:'HH')))&&((post.CreatedDate | date:'mm')< (time)))"
```

Code in TS page for present time + 5 minutes

```
const d: Date = new Date();
this.PresentDate = d;
var x = new Date();
d.getHours(); // => 9
d.getMinutes(); // =>  30
this.time = d.getMinutes() +5;
this.hours = d.getHours();
```

Please help with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Long expression in html is not good practice.

`*ngIf="canDeletePost(post)"`

```
canDeletePost(post) {
 return Date.now() - post.CreatedDate.getTime() <  5 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

If `CreatedDate` is Js date. 5 * 60 * 1000 - 5 min in milliseconds. Actually, have a method in `ngIf` is not good practice also.

Anyway, you don't need date pipe. Pipes is used for changing view.